# Can hostnames be formed by only numbers?

Tags: validation, ip, hostname

I'm implementing an IP/hostname validator. I'm testing the following input:

"10.0.0.1111"

Which is an invalid IP address, but I'm not sure if this is an invalid hostname as well because in [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_host_names) I read that hostnames can start and end with numbers characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123#page-13, this is invalid hostname as well.

```
    "However, a valid host name can never
       have the dotted-decimal form #.#.#.#, since at least the
       highest-level component label will be alphabetic."
```

Comment: I have a doubt, in www.google.com, "the highest-level component label" is "com" or "google" ?